# How do you interpret ANOVA with transformed response?

Tags: regression, anova, data-transformation

Let's say I have a quantitative variable Y that ranges between 0 and 1.  I have a categorical variable X that has 3 levels, A, B, C.  Since Y ranges between 0 and 1, I transform all of Y using the logit transformation so that logit(Y) = ln(Y / (1 - Y))

I build the model logit(Y) = A + B + C, with no intercept, and thus the coefficients basically tell me mean logit(Y) given A.

However, I don't want mean logit(Y) given A, I want mean Y given A.   Should I do my ANOVA without  transforming my Y.  Note that my final model will have both categorical and continuous predictors.  That is, lets say Z is a continuous variable.  Should I do:

- logit(Y) = A + B + C + Z
- Y = A + B + C + Z

Thanks

Comment: Likely I would do neither, but in some situations possibly either one -- there's not really enough information. Where possible, I'd look at something like a generalized linear model so that your model will both respect the bounds on the variable *and* give you a way to get  inference about the mean response fairly directly. Can you say more about $Y$, please. What makes it stay between 0 and 1? e.g. Is it a count proportion, or a continuous proportion, or maybe something else?  Can it be *exactly* 0 and/or *exactly* 1 but is otherwise continuous?

Comment: It's a continuous proportion, i.e. amount out of 100.  I'm just trying to get the mean Y  given X controlling for a bunch other predictors.

Comment: Again, can you say more about $Y$, please. Can you observe 0's and 1's? What sort of thing is it? (e.g. is it a spatial thing like proportion of land area? Is it a mixture of substances or chemicals? something else?)

Comment: Its the proportion of a loan that is lost due to defualt.

Comment: Ah, useful. It would be worth adding a lot of these details to your question. Presumably you can't have 0's (if you paid the whole loan presumably it's not a default), but you might have 1's. My first thought would be a beta regression (possibly 1-inflated or 0-1 inflated).